# Debugger breaks with Args out of range: "", 0

Tags: debugging, debug, sqlite

When [forge](https://github.com/magit/forge) is installed on a system with no compiler, I sometimes get [this error](https://github.com/skeeto/emacsql/blob/a118b6c95af1306f0288a383d274b5dd93efbbda/emacsql-sqlite.el#L194) which breaks magit. I'd like to figure out the traceback for this error so I can add some proper error handling, however, when I call `(toggle-debug-on-error)` every time this error is suppose to happen the debugger doesn't show but instead shows `Args out of range: "", 0`. The debugger seems to trigger successfully on other errors. I'm using GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32)

Comment: For what it's worth, I can reproduce this problem exactly. I do not know why neither `toggle-debug-on-error` nor `toggle-debug-on-message` works for this error.